# DLL error when importing tensorflow in anaconda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I have installed tensorflow in the anaconda environment. I have installed the latest anaconda and tensorflow by "conda install tensorflow-gpu". When I try to import tensorflow it works in the jupyter notebook. But the same code does run when I try to run from python terminal or when I run by "start debugging" from vs code. This is the error I am getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 410, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 291, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "d:\Projects\SASRec\SASRec Pytorch\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can anyone kindly give me a solution and make my life easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably already had some version of python installed (e.g. 3.6.6) before installing Anaconda with Python 3.7 and prepared it to use TensorFlow.
Because Anaconda comes with its own instance of Python you have installed the TensorFlow dependencies into the Anaconda instance of Python.

When you use the console, you most likely use your non-Anaconda-Python instance, which does not have TensorFlow with all its dependencies installed.

You can either install the missing dependencies for your non-Anaconda-Python or start the script with the Anaconda version of Python. You can do the later by calling python using the full path like `/path/to/anaconda/bin/python yourscriptusingtensorflow.py` or prepending the anaconda binary path to your console's $PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks, but I have not installed any other version of python other than anaconda. The solution that worked for me is to install an older version of tensorflow. I am adding this as an answer so that if for some reason someone faces the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of installing, uninstalling and reinstalling and scraping various similar issues in github and stackoverflow, I got a pretty simple solution. In my system, I only have Anaconda installed and c++ build tools from Microsoft (2019), and nothing else. Then I installed tensorflow as follows:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.10
```

Apparently, this older version is compatible with the DLL and everything seems to work.